# Error Message: out of gas

Tags: transactions, uniswap, contract-debugging, error

when making a swap via IUniswapV2Router(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amount, 1, path, address(this), deadline) on Goerli i got the following error on Tenderly:
[image]

Comment: What is the question exactly here?

Comment: How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the error, you should **supply more gas**. Currently, your gas limit is 100k gas. Sometimes it happens that Metamask evaluates transactions wrongly, so you have to set the gas limit manually.

If you are using Metamask, this is how you can do it:
https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015488771-How-to-adjust-Gas-Price-and-Gas-Limit